# What is the difference and relationship between the binomial and Bernoulli distributions?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

How should I understand the difference or relationship between binomial and Bernoulli distribution?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

A Bernoulli random variable has two possible outcomes:  $0$ or $1$.  A binomial distribution is the sum of **independent** and **identically** distributed Bernoulli random variables.

So, for example, say I have a coin, and, when tossed, the probability it lands heads is $p$.  So the probability that it lands tails is $1-p$ (there are no other possible outcomes for the coin toss).  If the coin lands heads, you win one dollar.  If the coin lands tails, you win nothing.

For a *single* coin toss, the probability you win one dollar is $p$.  The random variable that represents your winnings after one coin toss is a Bernoulli random variable.

Now, if you toss the coin $5$ times, your winnings could be any whole number of dollars from zero dollars to five dollars, inclusive. The probability that you win five dollars is $p^5$, because each coin toss is independent of the others, and for each coin toss the probability of heads is $p$.

What is the probability that you win *exactly* three dollars in five tosses?  That would require you to toss the coin five times, getting exactly three heads and two tails. This can be achieved with probability $\binom{5}{3} p^3 (1-p)^2$.  And, in general, if there are $n$ Bernoulli trials, then the sum of those trials is binomially distributed with parameters $n$ and $p$.

Note that a binomial random variable with parameter $n = 1$ is equivalent to a Bernoulli random variable, i.e. there is only one trial.

Comment: How should I read $\binom{5}{3} p^3 (1-p)^2$ ?
Please understand if I am asking you the very basic thing, I am new to it.

Comment: Say we represent the outcome of the five coin tosses as a list, and three of those tosses must be heads.  So we can have $$\begin{align*}&\{H,H,H,T,T\}, \\ &\{H,H,T,H,T\}, \\ &\{H,H,T,T,H\}, \\ &\{H,T,H,H,T\}, \\ &\{H,T,H,T,H\}, \\ &\{H,T,T,H,H\}, \\ &\{T,H,H,H,T\}, \\ &\{T,H,H,T,H\}, \\ &\{T,H,T,H,H\}, \\ &\{T,T,H,H,H\}. \end{align*}$$  As you can see, there are $\binom{5}{3} = 10$ ways to choose the positions of the three heads among the five tosses; and for each of these outcomes, the probability of observing three heads is $p^3$ and two tails is $(1-p)^2$.

Comment: I want to point out this answer doesn’t answer the specific question in the original post - that is, what is the difference between a Bernoulli *distribution* and a binomial *distribution*. Michael Hardy’s answer below addresses this specific question.

Comment: This is simply the best explanation...thanks

Answer (score 31):

All Bernoulli distributions are binomial distributions, but most binomial distributions are not Bernoulli distributions.

If
$$
X=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{with probability }p, \\ 0 & \text{with probability }1-p, \end{cases}
$$
then the probability distribution of the random variable $X$ is a Bernoulli distribution.

If $X=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ and each of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ has a Bernoulli distribution with the same value of $p$ and they are independent, then $X$ has a binomial distribution, and the possible values of $X$ are $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$.  If $n=1$ then that binomial distribution is a Bernoulli distribution.

Comment: One question, if $n=1$ then why is $X_{i}$ a `distribution` ?

Comment: @NeelBasu : $X_i$ is not a distribution; rather $X_i$ _has_ a distribution. $X_i$ is a random variable.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: you said $ X_1, ..., X_n $ has a Bernoulli distribution with the same value of $ p $... Does each random variable of X need to have the same value of p to be identically distributed?

Comment: @ChangheeKang : "Identically distributed" means having the same probability distribution. If the value of $p$ is altered, so is the probability distribution.

Comment: Since there's only two outcomes X=0 and X=1, is it always the case that a Bernoulli distribution is essentially two points, one of height p(X=0) and the other (necessarily) of height 1 - p(X=0) ?

Comment: What are examples of binomial distribution that are not Bernoulli distribution?

Answer (score 23):

A Bernoulli distribution is a special case of binomial distribution. Specifically, when $n=1$ the binomial distribution becomes Bernoulli distribution.

Comment: Most concise answer here, not sure why it's not at the top.

Comment: @A_for_Abacus If this answer explained what n was, I would have voted it up too.

Answer (score 2):

A Bernoulli random variable $X$ is a random variable that satisfies $P(X=1)=p$, $P(X=0)=1-p$. A canonical example is a coin flip which has $p=1/2$. In fact, you can think of a Bernoulli random variable is just a weighted coin, which comes up $1$ with some probability and $0$ otherwise. A binomial random variable with parameters $n,p$ is what you get when you count the number of $1$'s (successes) that come up in a string of $n$ independent Bernoulli random variables, each with parameter $p$. Another way to say this is that a binomial random variable is the sum of independent and identically distributed Bernoulli random variables.